# How could I nest two RecyclerView in a ScrollView and disable scrollview's scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a activity like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.hyqfx.recyclerviewtest.LockScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycler_view_1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="400dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycler_view_2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="400dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</com.hyqfx.recyclerviewtest.LockScrollView>
```

and the LockScrollView like this:

```
public class LockScrollView extends ScrollView {
  public LockScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public LockScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public LockScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

In this situation, the scrollview will no scroll first, but when the recyclerview scroll to the bottom, the parent scrollview work again.

But I want the scrollview do not work ever.

Someone can help me? thanks very much!

Comment: instead disable scrollview's scroll remove that scrollview and make LinearLayout android:layout_height as match_parent

Comment: If do this, the second recyclerview will be cut，I need it keep  400dp height.

Comment: did u tried NestedScrollView ? instead LockScrollView  try NestedScrollView and check it

Comment: It has the same result.

Comment: can you post NestedScrollView code part by how you tried? i want to know how you used.

Comment: I just made my LockScrollView extend the NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

You can use this way either :
Add this line to your `recyclerView` xml view :

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

try it ,`recyclerview` will be smoothly scrolled with flexible height

hope this helped .

Comment: It made the recyclerview no scroll.